# concurrent count request optimization

Tags: clickhouse

I have a table listing all the checkin and checkout of people from a building.
My aim is to count how many people were in the building at specific time (like every hours).

Here is my table:

```
CREATE TABLE checkins
(
    date_in DateTime, 
    date_out DateTime, 
    age Int32, 
    sex String, 
    date_day Date MATERIALIZED toDate(date_in)
) ENGINE = MergeTree(date_day, date_in, 8192)
```

Example data

```
INSERT INTO checkins VALUES
    (toDateTime('2018-01-01 08:30:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 16:30:00'), 32, 'M'), 
    (toDateTime('2018-01-01 09:30:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 10:30:00'), 28, 'M'), 
    (toDateTime('2018-01-01 10:15:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 10:45:00'), 30, 'M'),
    (toDateTime('2018-01-01 11:30:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 11:45:00'), 35, 'M'), 
    (toDateTime('2018-01-01 14:30:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 17:30:00'), 25, 'F');
```

I am currently calculating the number of people in the building this way:

```
SELECT count(*), instant
FROM 
(
    SELECT arrayJoin([toDateTime('2018-01-01 10:00:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 12:00:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 14:00:00'), toDateTime('2018-01-01 16:00:00')] AS tabinstants) AS instant
    FROM checkins 
    WHERE (date_in < instant) AND (date_out > instant)
) 
GROUP BY instant
ORDER BY instant ASC
```

which returns as expected

```
┌─count()─┬─────────────instant─┐
│       2 │ 2018-01-01 10:00:00 │
│       1 │ 2018-01-01 12:00:00 │
│       1 │ 2018-01-01 14:00:00 │
│       2 │ 2018-01-01 16:00:00 │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

However this request seems to not be scalable : it is really slow with a lot of points in the array and lines in the table. I assume this is because of the size of the joined data. Is there a mechanism that would allow computing this data more efficiently ?

Second question:
How could I do if I now want to have the max number of person between each point ?

e.g. 
between 10:00 and 12:00 I had maximum 3 people (at 10:15)

```
┌─count()─┬─────────────instant─┐
│       3 │ 2018-01-01 10:00:00 │ 
│       1 │ 2018-01-01 12:00:00 │
│       2 │ 2018-01-01 14:00:00 │
│       2 │ 2018-01-01 16:00:00 │
└─────────┴─────────────────────┘
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try operator `timeSlots` which generate array of 30-minute periods.
`arrayFilter` to filter midle of hours, so you will have hour periods.
So your query will be like this

`SELECT count(*), instant
FROM 
(
    SELECT arrayJoin(arrayFilter(x -> toStartOfHour(x) = x, timeSlots(toDateTime('2018-01-01 08:00:00'), toUInt32(toDateTime('2018-01-01 20:00:00') - toDateTime('2018-01-01 08:00:00')))) AS tabinstants) AS instant
    FROM checkins 
    WHERE (toStartOfHour(date_in) <= instant) AND (toStartOfHour(date_out)  + 3600 > instant)
) 
GROUP BY instant
ORDER BY instant ASC`

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
The problem I have for the arrayjoin part is I want to be able to go down to 5-minutes periods. But generating the array is not a problem for me.

Regarding your proposition for the second question, it does not work the way I want. For example if I have someone in from 10:15 to 10:30 and someone from 10:45 to 11:00 it will count two people for the 10:00 to 11:00 slot while it was at most one.

Comment: Regarding the second question, to solve the problem you describer you can change condition to 
`WHERE (toStartOfHour(date_in) <= instant) AND (toStartOfHour(date_out - 1) + 3600> instant)`

Comment: If you need 5-minutes intervals. You can use `range(N)` to generate array of int, and then `arrayMap` to convert it to 5-minutes intervals.

`SELECT count(*), instant
FROM 
(
    SELECT arrayJoin(arrayMap(x -> 300*x + toDateTime('2018-01-01 08:00:00'), range(toUInt32((toDateTime('2018-01-01 20:00:00') - toDateTime('2018-01-01 08:00:00'))/300))) AS tabinstants) AS instant
    FROM checkins 
    WHERE (toStartOfFiveMinute(date_in) <= instant) AND (toStartOfFiveMinute(date_out - 1)  + 300 > instant)
) 
GROUP BY instant
ORDER BY instant ASC`

Comment: Thanks for your continuous answers. Nice trick for the arrayMap, I'll use it ! Regarding the second issue the problem is not a border one. It counts every people that were in the slot, not the one that were at the same time. If I modify my example with one people from 10:15 to 10:20 and another one from 10:30 to 10:35, both will be counted for the 10:00 11:00 slot but there was at most 1 in the building at a given time.